# when calling class method by reference, how to have "this" still point to that class?

Tags: javascript

consider the below:

```
class foo(){
   constructor(){this.x = 10}
   f(){console.log(this.x)}
}
myfoo = new foo()
class bar{
    constructor()
    b(func){func()}
}
mybar = new bar()
mybar.b(myfoo.f)
```

Because of how this works in javascript, "this" in myfoo.f points to mybar instead of myfoo. How do i go around this? Also if anyone know, why does javascript do this?

Comment: You meant `mybar.b(myfoo.f)`, right? `mybar.b{myfoo.f()}` is not even valid syntax.

Comment: @Bergi, yep typo